# Set p:calendar date and time to DefaultScheduleEvent's startDate and endDate

Tags: datetime, jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:schedule` which has a `p:ajax` of event dateSelect. A popup opens to be able to input `DefaultScheduleEvent` - title, startDate, endData, etc. I have referred to the code [here](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml).

However when I click `p:commandButton` which goes to an actionListener in the ManagedBean, the startDate and endDate are not set in the bean according to user input. Default values are stored. How can I take the user's input and use it in the Bean?

Front end xhtml:

```html
<p:panel header="Calendar" style="height:100%">
                    <p:schedule value="#{studentCalendarBean.eventModel}" leftHeaderTemplate="prev,next" draggable="false" rightHeaderTemplate="" widgetVar="viewSchedule" timeFormat="">
                        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" process="@this" listener="#{studentCalendarBean.onDateSelect}" update="addEventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventAddDialog').show();" />
                    </p:schedule>
                    <p:dialog widgetVar="eventAddDialog" header="Request New Lesson" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">
                    <h:panelGrid id="addEventDetails" columns="2">
                        <p:outputLabel for="title-a" value="Title:" />
                        <p:inputText id="title-a" value="#{studentCalendarBean.event.title}" required="true" valueChangeListener="#{studentCalendarBean.event.title}"/>

                        <p:outputLabel for="from-a" value="From:" />
                        <p:calendar id="from-a" value="#{studentCalendarBean.event.startDate}" timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" mask="99/99/9999 99:99">
                            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{studentCalendarBean.startDateChanged}" />
                        </p:calendar>

                        <p:outputLabel for="to-a" value="To:" />
                        <p:calendar id="to-a" value="#{studentCalendarBean.event.endDate}" timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" mask="99/99/9999 99:99"/>

                        <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />
                        <p:commandButton id="addEventButton" value="Schedule" actionListener="#{studentCalendarBean.scheduleNewEvent}" oncomplete="PF('viewSchedule').update();PF('eventAddDialog').hide();" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>
</p:panel>
```

Managed Bean Code:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped public class StudentCalendarBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4421935956943227260L;

private ScheduleModel eventModel;

private ScheduleEvent event;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
    //populate events calendar
    logger.info("StudentCalendarBean: Initializing");
    eventModel = getAllEvents(); //defined
}

public void scheduleNewEvent() {
    logger.info("StudentCalendarBean: Creating new schedule");
    //Having problem here - startDate and endDate are set to Default!!!!
    if (event.getId() == null) {
        Schedule newSchedule = new Schedule();
        if (validateEvent(event)) {
            newSchedule = newEventToNewSchedule(event);
        }
        //update database
        studentCalendarLogic.addNewSchedule(newSchedule);
        //update view
        eventModel.addEvent(event);
    }
    //reset default event
    event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
}

 public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    event = new DefaultScheduleEvent("", (Date) selectEvent.getObject(), (Date) selectEvent.getObject());
}


}
```

Comment: Is everything in a form?

Answer (score 0):

I see your calling...

```
value="#{studentCalendarBean.event.title}"
```

But I don't see a setter/getter for Event in your studentCalendarBean so how can it possibly get the value out of the event?

Comment: getters/setters not actually being present would result in errors (not always in PF btw ubfortunately). Unfortunately most people do not post a [mcve] (type [ mcve ] in a comment without spaces)